# Recibir información de una subscipción a un topic en Azure Service Bus

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure

Tengo una suscripción a un `topic` con filtros en ***Azure Service Bus*** hecha en ***Python*** y a la hora de recibir la información que se envía a ese `topic` (información que cumple con el filtro) no consigo recibirla.

Necesito crear un demonio que esté siempre escuchando y que cuando reciba esa información la envíe a un servicio interno de mi aplicación, por lo que el `receiver` está corriendo en un hilo dentro de un bucle `While True`

El código que uso para recibir los mensajes es el siguiente:

```
while True:
    msg = bus_service.receive_subscription_message(topic_name, subscription_name, peek_lock=True)
    print('Mensaje Recibido-->',msg.body)
    data = msg.body
    send_MyApp(data.decode("utf-8"))
    msg.delete()
```

Lo que recibo cuando lo ejecuto es lo siguiente:

```
Mensaje Recibido--> None
    Exception in thread Thread-1:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "../Python/ServiceBusSuscription/receive_subscription.py", line 19, in receive_subscription
        send_MyApp(data.decode("utf-8"))
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

No recibe la información que le he enviado y además salta un `timeout` del Service Bus (que yo no he programado).

¿Alguien puede ayudarme? La documentación de Microsoft no ayuda mucho, la verdad.

**UPDATE**

Si ejecuto el receiver fuera del hilo, este es el mensaje de error que muestra (otra vez cuando salta el timeout, timeout que deberé eliminar porque en un demonio que está a la espera no puede saltar)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../Python/ServiceBusSuscription/receive_subscription.py", line 76, in <module>
    main()
  File "../Python/ServiceBusSuscription/receive_subscription.py", line 72, in main
    demo(bus_service)
  File "../Python/ServiceBusSuscription//receive_subscription.py", line 25, in demo
    print(msg.body.decode("utf-8"))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

**UPDATE 2**
Creo que el problema es que la suscripción de Azure Service Bus solamente admite un filtro. Yo tenía 23, con lo que al lanzar el receiver, Azure Service Bus no me devuelve nada, es como si no ejecutara los filtros en mi suscripción, por eso no me devuelve nada y salta el timeout.

Comment: Deberías evitar el error  cuando no hay mensajes disponibles trás el timeout por defecto usando un condicional, `if msg.body: `, por ejemplo, Hecho esto investiga porqué no hay mensajes cuando debería haberlos. Tengo cero experiencia con Azure, por lo que es solo suposición, habría que saber que retorna el método cuando no hay mensajes. http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.servicebus.servicebusservice.html#azure.servicebus.servicebusservice.ServiceBusService.receive_subscription_message

Comment: Si, ya lo hago con if (len(data) != 0):  o  # if (data != 'NoneType'):, y sigue sin funcionar

Comment: De todas formas, el problema no es ese, el problema es que no llega información cuando debería de hacerlo. No se si es problema de versiones de Python o qué :(

Comment: Si es así, con el condicional no debes recibir ningún error. Si con el código actual no recibes ningún error el problema debe estar en otro lado, deberías buscar el problema antes, en el envío o en la configuración de azure. El trozo de código que expones no tiene ningún problema, deberías agregar lo que tienes antes del ciclo de lectura y asegurarte sin ninguna duda de que la información llega antes de presuponer que es un problema de lectura. El error lo único que muestra es que no hay nada que leer y al retornar un objeto `None` no puedes aplicar `decode` porque no es una cadena.

Comment: Creo que el problema es de los filtros Azure Service Bus, no de mi código. Qué hago, ¿elimino la pregunta?

Comment: Si estas seguro de ello, al menos tal y como esta la pregunta, deberías eliminarla ya que es imposible reproducir el problema dado que no es problema del código que planteas. No obstante, si encuentras el problema real y su solución puedes replantearla y autocontestarla si consideras que puede ser de ayuda a otros usuarios del sitio, siempre que el problema real tenga cabida en el sitio (de acuerdo a [help/on-topic] ) sera bienvenida. Un saludo.

Comment: Si, voy a esperar un poco para ver si algún experto en Azure Service Bus aquí o en SoF me confirma este punto. Además, acabo de preguntar en Meta qué hacer (https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2741/eliminar-una-pregunta-porque-el-problema-que-pregunta-es-diferente-al-que-se-sup)